# Timezone issue with java

Tags: java

When i run below code in my windows machine

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone iz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println(iz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis()) + "\t" + cal.getTime()
+ "\t" + cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName() + "\t" + iz.getDSTSavings());
```

Output:

```
10800000    Mon Apr 21 11:55:11 FET 2014    Further-Eastern European Time   0
```

But when same code is executed from my friend's machine, it says:

```
10800000    Mon Apr 21 11:55:11 FET 2014    Eastern European Time   3600000

Time Zone : (UTC+02:00) E. Europe
```

For other timezones I am getting proper result, but for this timezone it's giving some weird issue.

Please let me know what can be the issue? On what parameters timezone is dependent?
I googled the issue, but i was not able to find the solution or reason for the same.

---

Basically i want to convert any time which is coming from machine to `GMT/UTC` based on offset, but in this case when daylight saving is going on, the scenario fails.
Thanks in advance.

Here are some more information :
My Machine's calender object :
`java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1398072046600,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Minsk",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=69,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=17,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=21,DAY_OF_YEAR=111,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=20,SECOND=46,MILLISECOND=600,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]`

Friend's Machine's calendar object :
`java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1398072634915,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Minsk",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=121,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Minsk,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=1,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=1]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=17,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=21,DAY_OF_YEAR=111,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=30,SECOND=34,MILLISECOND=915,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]`

Comment: The only difference is java version, i am using JDK1.6_35 and friend is using JDK1.6_25

Answer (score 1):

Your timezone is UTC+3, your friends's timezone is UTC+2 but they apply daylight saving (3600000 ms = 1 hour), meaning their effective time is UTC+3. Therefore, your friend ends up with the same time as you. This looks perfectly normal. If your friend does not live in the Eastern Europe time zone, he should adjust the system settings on his computer.

Comment: We made changes to our system's time zone. and we made it same.

Comment: From the additional information you provided, they are **not** the same. Your system does not use daylight saving (useDaylight = false), his does (useDaylight = true).

Comment: yes that's what weird, as we both have same timezone configuration but we are getting different results, i don't know what can be the issue, is it with windows or java. Or it may be some configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks zoyd for your answer, i found the reason behind it, in my machine java 1.6_34 - where as in my friend's machine java 1.6_25 was installed. When we checked result after upgrading java, on both the machines result was same.